# Can we use phonegap plugins in Ionic Framework

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework, cordova-3

I am new in the Ionic Framework for developing applications. i want to know that is it possible to use [phonegap plugin](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins) in my Ionicframework application

Please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: Absolutely yes. Ionic can be a Phonegap. Indeed is the normal way to wrap it into app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have dought, can we use the same procedure to install a plugin which is used in phonegap CLI like as: "cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device" ???

Comment: Yes,  it is the same process as any other javascript framework.

Comment: Also check http://ngcordova.com/ a worthy addition when using angular JS from the Ionic team.

Comment: thank you  malcubierre and  VicM for your useful comment it's helpful for me